# Change the size of all asp:Label Text

Tags: html, css, asp.net, label

I have a LOT of `asp:Label`s and I want to change the size of the font for every single one.

I know that they are converted to `<span>` but I have other elements with text that get converted to spans which I *don't* want to change.
So how can I apply style to only the the spans generated from Labels all at once?

Please don't tell me I'll have to go through each one and apply a cssClass directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a Skin for that. Think of Skin as a set of settings common for all controls of specific type. Skins do not exist on their own, but within a theme. Here is a [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247256.aspx) on how to create a theme from MSDN. I do not think it is reasonable to copy it here.

But to focus on your specific use case, go ahead and follow this walkthrough and create a theme with only a single skin defined like so:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="CommonCssClass" />
```

Notice we do not use SkinID, so this will be applied to all `Label` controls.

Next go to the page and modify Page directive:

```
<%@ Page Theme="YourThemeName" %>
```

That's it, this should apply skin defined in the theme to the labels on the page.

In fact I would make an argument that this is a better way to do similar changes to server side controls then trying to figure out how to capture resulting HTML with css selector. The latter puts your code into dependency on the generated markup, which is dangerous as ASP.NET does not always generate what you would expect. For example, [Label does not always render as span](http://laumania.net/2011/06/08/make-asp-net-label-render-as-html-label-tag/).

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Is it possible to use this selectively too?  Like only on labels within `<fieldset>` or something?

Comment: @Nol, no afaik. Page is probably the narrowest scope you can apply this to. Or you could always use SkinID, but then it is no difference from just setting CssClass. The last option I see though is assign skin in code behind, where you can probably distinguish controls better. But bear in mind that this can be done only during PreInit phase, not later